# Comments and Testimonials on Profile 2 Profiles

Tags: theming, comments, users

Is there a way of enabling either comments or a guestbook/testimonial functionality on Profile 2 Profiles?

I've read discussions on here about implementing on User Account Pages but not for the Profile 2 Profiles module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module called [reply](https://www.drupal.org/project/reply), that is intended as a solution for fieldable comments on non-node entities and should work with any entities created via the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module, which includes [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) entities.